# How to use handler: 'string' in joomla modals

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, editor, modal

Im looking for some examples of how to use {handler: 'string' ...} for joomla modals, as used in editors-xtd buttons plugins

```
$button->options = '{handler: 'iframe' ......}';
```

but I want to use:

```
$button->modal = true;
$button->options = "{handler: 'string', content: 'some content'}";
```

but I haven't found any information for the proper usage of this or if this really works. 
I have spent many days trying to get it to work, I tried with several var names setting variables like `$button->content` or `$button->html`, or inside the $button->options, but nothing worked for me.
Thanks in advance!